# Data template does not set data context WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using WPF and MVVM. I set the DataContext of my main window to be a NavigationViewModel(which handles navigation). It looks like this:

```
 public class NavigationVM : BaseVM
 {
     private BaseVM? selectedViewModel;

     public NavigationVM()
     {
         var optionsVM = new OptionsVM(this);
         SelectedViewModel = optionsVM; 
     }
     
     public BaseVM SelectedViewModel
     {
         get { return selectedViewModel!; }
         set
         {
             selectedViewModel = value;
             OnPropertyChanged(nameof(selectedViewModel));
         }
     }
 }
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
   <Window.ContentTemplate>
    
    <DataTemplate DataType="viewmodels:OptionsVM">
        <views:Options></views:Options>
    </DataTemplate>
    
</Window.ContentTemplate>
   

    <UserControl Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel}"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                 VerticalAlignment ="Center"/>
```

This type of navigation works just fine.

In NavigationVM's constructor, I set `SelectedViewModel` to be a OptionsVM(), and it works. The view displayed is my Option view (it's just a usercontrol with 5 buttons).

The problem is I thought that whenever a OptionsVM is created and the Options vew set, that that set that Option's data context to the ViewModel:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="viewmodels:OptionsVM">
        <views:Options></views:Options>
    </DataTemplate>
```

But when trying to bind the button's command property to a property in the ViewModel, those properties are not found, meaning the data context of the view is not actually set to the ViewModel.
How can I set the data context of my view to its ViewModel?

Comment: How is the ContentTemplate of a Window supposed to be applied to the Content of a UserControl? It seems you wanted to declare the DataTemplate in `<Window.Resources>`.

Comment: OnPropertyChanged(nameof(selectedViewModel))

Comment: Should be capital S

Comment: Also make sure your Options control does not explicitly set its own DataContext, neither in XAML nor in code behind.

Comment: @Clemens if I use window.resources it doesnt display the view, it just displays "OptionsViewModel.cs"

Comment: Use a ContentControl instead of a UserControl: `<ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel}" .../>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be automatically selected, a DataTemplate must be declared as XAML resource, e.g. in `Window.Resources`.

Its `DataType` property must be set by the `x:Type` markup extension, a simple type name string won't work.

You would also use a `ContentControl` to apply a `DataTemplate` for a certain content type:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:OptionsVM}">
            <views:Options/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel}"/>
</Window>
```

---

You must also make sure that the Options control does not explicitly set its own DataContext.

---

In your view model, you must use the name of the property, not that of its backing field, to notify about property changes:

```
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedViewModel));
```

Comment: oh my...intellisense autocompleted it without "x:Type" so  I thought it should work.That was the problem..thanks<3